# Error:(42, 70) java: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

So I am trying to run java rest api on **IntelliJ** but I have the exception from the title of this question:

> Error:(42, 70) java: underscores in literals are not supported in
>   -source 1.6   (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)

I am using java 13 and it is on mac.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please check "Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler" settings. Probably wrong language level is used for compilation.

Comment: Does any of the answers in this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788743/intellij-error-java-release-version-10-not-supported/58152911#58152911

Comment: (The cause of course is having literals like `1_000_000`.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you are using JDK 1.6 instead of 13, that you want

If you run your project using the buttons availables in IntelliJ (play, stop, debug...)

Go to file > project structure and make sure that all of your modules, sources and projects are using java 13:

[project SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Hc0.png)

[source SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBOgn.png)

[dependencies SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4nQB.png)

If you don't have java 13 setted, configure new Java Home pointing to your Java 13 folder:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.[your version].jdk/Contents/Home/

If you run your project using terminal, make sure you are using Java 13 by typping:

java -version

Comment: Well, I have done all of those and I still have the exception.