# Failed to execute goal in apache maven IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner to maven and trying to make a project and successfully build it in IntelliJ Idea. My pom.xml is as follows:

> xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 [http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22%3E)
> 4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>jetbrains</groupId>
> <artifactId>EAN-Scraper</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <properties>
>     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>     <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
> </properties>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
>         <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
>         <version>2.53.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
>         <version>1.13.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
>         <version>1.4</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
>     <!-- Source directory configuration -->
>     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>1.8}</source>
>                 <target>1.8</target>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build> </project>
> ```

And the error that I get is

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project EAN-Scraper: Fatal error compiling

I already tried the changes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601077/intellij-errorjava-error-release-version-5-not-supported). My jdk version is 13. My project structure is attached below [image]

Comment: There was an error in my plugin tag, Changed it to <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
and it built successfully.

Comment: What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the declaration of the compiler plugin:

`<source>1.8}</source>`