# intellij java version 5 DOgs

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I get an error when I try to build the project

i get this error java: error: release version 5 not supported

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQfTx.png)

Comment: Please check language level in "Project Structure | Project/Modules" and target bytecode in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler"

Comment: Good to take the first step to ask a question on SO but please don't mind as I would like to give you some comment about your first question. 1. others are unable to reproduce your problem as there is too little information, e.g. what environment are you using (IntelliJ IDEA version, which OS, etc) 2. unclear on the title, I'm not sure what are you asking, and is DOgs a short form for something? 3. search if any similar problem on SO, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601077/intellij-errorjava-error-release-version-5-not-supported seems like the problem you're asking.