# Error: Repeatedly getting error 'Java 14 not supported

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-14

Trying to learn Spring-Boot, and improving my Java skills.  I keep getting error stating that '..*java: error: release version 14 not supported*..'.  My jdk is set for jdk-11 on preferences page.  I cannot find where the jdk version is set to 14.  Any ideas where to look?  I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, with latest versions of Kite and Spring-Boot.  Here is my scanner script to use for exploration of Scanner uses and library but I don't think this is the problem.

package com.hoytchilds.JavaPrograms;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The integer you entered is: " + sc);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Do you use Maven or gradle? Check the https://stackoverflow.com/a/59607812/2000323

Comment: Maven.  Don't know enough about either one yet to feel confident in using either.  But IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate includes these, as well as ANT.  I have slowly found and eliminated references to JDK > 11.   So far, problem persists.

Comment: Does it work when you do `mvn clean install` in project directory in terminal? Check the answer I linked. Configure in Maven to use source and target release to be the `11`. And make sure the [Project JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk) and [module JDKs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html#module-sdk) are all point to 11 JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate which includes plugs for Maven.  How does one do a clean install in this situation?  Other than being sure the IDE and the plugins are UTD, I see no way to do it.